# HDD shows up as "no data" on it and can't be initialized in Windows

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, partition-recovery, hard-drive-failure, disk-management

I have a physically undamaged 2.5 inch HDD (Hitachi 5400RPM 320GB) when I connect it with an sata to usb convertor windows doesn't react on it. When I open the windows disk management software it shows up. With this messages:

- No data
- Not initialized

Googling gave me the results only in cases when you can create a partition but in my case it doesn't even show up as unallocated. Also I took of the PCB to clean the contact pads but nothing changed.
What could I possibly do to recover this drive? (Not the data just the functionality)

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the adapter.  You should try a different adapter.  If after you try a different adapter, and the behavior is the same, you can assume the drive cannot be recovered without special hardware.  At that point I would send it to a data recovery company, they have tools and experience, to transplant your platters to a working drive to recover the data.  *Most recovery companies will NOT even attempt data recovery if you break the seal to the drive.*  In other words, try a different adapter, then escalate the problem to a professional.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your suggestion. I already connected the drive directly to the sata ports on my motherboard and everything is the same. Obviously the drive is dead. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dissembling the drive I saw that one of the platters was damaged. On the outer side (I think that important data to initialize correctly is stored there). There where several black lines that where scratches from a reading head that fell off. That again demonstrates that hard drives can't be diagnosed at home without harm for them. So to recover data I recommend don't even try to fix it yourself because you can cause data damage so that no company could recover it.